# Serializing a List<List<String>> infinite loop iterator.hasNext() JAVA

Tags: java, list, serialization

I've been trying to serialize a `List<List< String >>` in Java but my code gets stucks in a loop. Here's the code:

```
 public void Serializing(List<List<String>> player,File file ) throws IOException{
        
        try {
            fileOut=new FileOutputStream(file);
            out= new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            Iterator <List <String>> it=player.listIterator();
          while(it.hasNext()){ //Somehow if i don't put this just adds my first element 
              out.writeObject(player.listIterator().next());
            }
            fileOut.close();
            out.close();
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ManejoInformacion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I'm adding the deserializable method just in case

```
public  List<List<String>> deserializable(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        ObjectInputStream in;
        List<List<String>> info;
        try (FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            in =new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            info = new ArrayList<>();
            info =(List<List<String>>)in.readObject();
         }      in.close();
        return info;
    }
```

Hope this is enough! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
out.writeObject(player.listIterator().next());
```

you're creating a new iterator. But you already had an iterator, and you need to use that one so its state is updated.

```
out.writeObject(it.next());
```

Otherwise `it.hasNext()` stays true because you're not taking items from `it`.

Alternatively, get rid of all reference to iterators, get rid of the while-loop, and just use a for-loop:

```
for (List<String> item: player) {
    out.writeObject(item);
}
```

The for-loop handles the iterator implicitly, so you don't have to.

Comment: Another question, I have a list inside a node of a list and when I deserialize it, returns the first value, but in the serialization works perfectly, I made the changes, but I don't know what might could've happened... It's like the deserialization doesn't return the same structure (list in a node of a list)

Comment: Well why is it that you write each element of `player` individually but you read them all at once? Wouldn't it make more sense to just `out.writeObject(player)`?